# Game of Thrones: Jojen and Meera look like Theon and Yara?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Jojen and Meera look very much like younger versions of Theon and Yara.

Is it just mere coincidence that the characters look alike (and my wild imagination) or is there more to it?

Why do I have some strange feeling it all has to do with some sort of redemption of Theon for what he did to Starks / Bran Stark. Are we yet to see in books/tv shows the truth behind this?

[image: Jojen meera theon yara]

Comment: Why would a Theon redemption have anything to do with him looking like Jojen?

Comment: There's nothing in the books about that

Comment: If you want food for thought about Theon, consider that he killed the miller's boys, and he had slept with the miller's wife "once or twice". Then consider the stories Old Nan told about kinslayers.

Comment: @TLP - An excellent question. I rather suspect that this is merely fan-theory run riot.

Comment: I don't see a resemblance and I don't see any relevance here either; are you quite sure that you're not looking for something you *want* to be the case here?

Comment: Going by fan speculations, I would *love* to see Joffrey, of all people, being redeemed. Would Joffrey Hitlering himself be considered redemption?

Comment: Meera looks bugger all like a young Yara, beyond being female. I’ll give you Jojen looking a bit like a young Theon, but both actors are pretty well-known in the UK, so it’s not surprising they got cast. (The chap who plays Jojen was in Doctor Who’s World War One episode from series 3.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is one of the more shall we say "speculative" questions I have seen on here! I don't think there is much of a resemblance and I certainly don't think there's an overreaching story arc on the subject. IF there is ANY kind of resemblance in the TV show (and I am not saying there is), the most likely explanation for that would be that Hollywood/TV producers tend to recruit actors/actresses who fit a certain type or image that is expected of such casts, making the recruitment of similar-looking people for the cast more likely. Or it could just be a coincidence...

Answer (score 3):

The show's canon is the books of the Song of Ice and Fire series. No physical resemblance is ever noted or commented upon between Jojen and Theon, or Meera and Asha (Yara in the TV series). So I would say that this resemblance (if it exists) is a mere coincidence and not an indicator of anything deep.

Comment: I'm not sure that anyone in the books has actually seen both Meera and Asha, and very few people have seen both Theon and Jojen (only Bran and Rickon, I think). So it's not likely that a resemblance could have been noted.

Comment: @MikeScott - The whole of Winterfell have seen both Theon and Jojen. And a few of them have seen Asha when she came to *rescue* Theon.

Answer (score 0):

My wife and I immediately noted the resemblance when Jojen and Meera were first introduced.

Beyond the physical resemblance, it was notable that Meera uses a bow, and has mannerisms that are much like Yara's.

Perhaps, as suggested elsewhere, the author (and the show's casting dept) are guilty of using stock character and casting types.

But there is definitely a strong similarity.